# vlookup values from other sheets disappear when file closed

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I've got a group of registers that I created for our volunteers and youth club members. Each register spreadsheet is from Sept to July. More and more volunteers and young people are staying with us for longer so I have been trying to create a vlookup that takes the total hours they volunteered from the previous years and add it to the current year total. This chains about 3-4 previous years of registers together. ie, 2014-15 adds to 2015-16 total, 2015-16 adds to 2016-17 total, 2016-17 adds to 2017-18 total, etc. The vlookup works great when all the previous years registers are open, but once I close one I get a #n/a error. How can I prevent the error msg and keep my formula working without opening all the documents?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the complete workbook path in your vlookup formula?

I.e. something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,'C:\School Projects\University\[Assignment.xlsx]DataYear'!$A3:$D10,3,FALSE)
```

Where:

`Assignment.xlsx` - is the name of workbook

`DataYear` - is the name of the worksheet

---

**EDIT:**

Since you mention you have tables when you are using your VLOOKUP you should use the Index + Match, is way more flexible. [#Data] won't work and VLOOKUP works best only if the return column is next to the search column, i.e. Column 1 is search and Column 2 is return values.

**Example of applying INDEX + MATCH in table:**

If I have an table in Book2.xlsx

[image]

And my table is named table 15:

[image]

Let's assume I have another woorkbook (Book1.xlsx). I want to check how many Quantity the person Sally sold. (My formula should return: 2, Cell `C3`).
Then my formula should be in the other excel book (Book1.xlsx):

```
=INDEX('G:\Folder Stuff\Book2.xlsx'!Table15[Qty],MATCH(B2,'G:\Folder Stuff\Book2.xlsx'!Table15[People],0))
```

So to apply for tables you should use:

```
Table15[Qty] - Return quantity, which refer to my column Qty in my example
Table15[People] - column to lookup my search value (sally), which refer to my column People in my example
```

[image]

Logic of INDEX + MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Column where result should be return,MATCH(lookup_value, Column where lookup value exist, Exact or Approximate Match)
```

---

So your formula should be something like this:

=INDEX('C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox...\Registers\Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx'!Table14[**Name of the table column in Column 37**],MATCH(StudentLookup,'C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox...\Registers\Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx'!Table14[**Name of the table Column where StudentLookup exist**],0))

Comment: This is the formula I have used:
VLOOKUP(StudentLookup,'C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox\...\Registers\Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx'!Table14[#Data],37,FALSE)
I was wondering if the #data was correct but it doesn't seem to work when I use the column number so stuck with it

Comment: Looking at your example, should it be:
VLOOKUP(StudentLookup,'C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox\COG Youth Services Ltd\Staff & Directors\Registers\[Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx]StudentList'!AL4,37,FALSE)
or
VLOOKUP(StudentLookup,'C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox\COG Youth Services Ltd\Staff & Directors\Registers\[Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx]StudentList'!B4:AL75,37,FALSE)

Comment: It should be the second one: `VLOOKUP(StudentLookup,'C:\Users\COG Youth Services\Dropbox\COG Youth Services Ltd\Staff & Directors\Registers[Volunteers attendance record 2017-18.xlsx]StudentList'!B4:AL75,37,FALSE)`, because you're looking at a range, when you do a VLOOKUP. The vlookup formula consists of: VLOOKUP(lookup_value,range_where_to_look,column_to_return_value_from,exact_orapproximate_match)